# What do you call $-f(x)$

Tags: notation, terminology

I have a terminology question. I am referring to a sigmoid (S-shape function) in a paper however it is inverted (if the sigmoid is $f(x)$, my function $-f(x)$).

I initially wanted to refer to it as an inverse sigmoid... but I think that would refer to $f^{-1}(x)$ ?

Any help welcome! thank you

Comment: I do not think "inverted sigmoid" would refer to $f^{-1}(x)$.  Maybe "inverse sigmoid" would, but even that probably needs more explanation before using it.

Comment: good point, I edited the post

Comment: Another option could be additive inverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that *negated* is the right name:
$f(x)$ *negated* is $-f(x)$

Answer (score 2):

If you multiplied by $-1$ then the symbol is $-f(x)$.
If you found the inverse function (then the composition is the identity) then the symbol is $f^{-1}(x)$

Comment: hi tota, thanks for your input. My question is actually, how do you call -f?

Comment: We call in mathematics the "opossite function " I think, (my tongue language is sapnish, in spanish we call the "opuesta"

Comment: opposit is the correct term for an additive inverse in all algebraic structure with an addition.

Comment: I am not familiar with this terminology, although I think I would probably guess correctly what was meant. "Opposite sigmoid" is a perfectly good name, but I would advise you to explain in the paper what you mean by it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [graziano governatori](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/232890/1543) that "negated sigmoid" is a good name.

Another possibility is "reflected sigmoid".

But as [Matt Pressland](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232865/how-do-you-call-fx/232890#comment516836_232868) wrote, whatever terminology you chose in the end you should clearly define it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to stress. If you only mean a left-right flipped S shape, I think it is usually called a "**negative** sigmoid" ([example 1 on p.4](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~leortiz/teaching/6.034f/Fall04/neural_nets/nnets-2002f.pdf), [example 2](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=jDbrma5YP64C&pg=PA204&lpg=PA204&dq=%22negative%20sigmoid%22&source=bl&ots=YWxat3_SSS&sig=x5dZ-zViAgSHycxldqYWuyqSpEc&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ei=CsGbUITyD-iUiAe-vID4Dg&ved=0CCgQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22negative%20sigmoid%22&f=false), [example 3 on p.4](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~sczhu/papers/Conf_2012/Tangram_vehicle_WACV2012.pdf)). However, logistic-like functions with negative parameters such as $1/(1+e^{-(-x)})$ are also called negative sigmoids. Certainly, such functions can be written in the form of
$$\mathtt{constant} + \mathtt{negative\ multiple} * \mathtt{some\ sigmoid}(x),$$
but the stress here is the shape of the curve rather the negative multiple itself.

If you want to stress that the function is constructed by multiplying a sigmoid function by a negative number, I don't know the proper name, but I agree with the others here that "**negated** sigmoid" is a good name. Yet, a [google search on "negated sigmoid"](https://www.google.com/#hl=zh-TW&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=%22negated+sigmoid%22&oq=%22negated+sigmoid%22&gs_l=hp.3...13580.18662.0.18991.17.17.0.0.0.0.79.1038.17.17.0...0.0...1c.1.Yrn5FzgSXmY&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=5b55eb663b4c1d13&bpcl=37643589&biw=1024&bih=609) returns only 25 results. So this is perhaps not a very common name.